# Edit event and pass it to parent

Tags: jquery, events

Having a structure like:

```
<div id="a">
  <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

With Ember.js I can attach this event handler to `#b`:

```
Ember.on('click', function(evt) {
  evt.a = true;
});
```

Doing so, the parent element `#a` will receive the edited `evt` if I attach to it an event handler:

```
Ember.on('click', function(evt) {
  evt.a; // true
});
```

I'd like to do the same with jQuery but I can't find a way to do it, do I need to destroy the event end trigger the new one manually? I'd prefer some built-in way.

Comment: You need to stop the propagation of the event in the div "b" and trigger the same event modified (not a new one) at the parent element. If you want an example I could do an example for you.